# Resizing a part of a formula

Tags: equations, fontsize

How can I change the size of a part of a formula by analogy with the built-in formula:

[image]

```
$$\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$$

$\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$ \Large $e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$ \normalsize
```

Comment: Maybe what you want is `\dfrac{}{}` for inline math mode. Also, use `\sin`.

Comment: But then the size of the constant _e_ will remain small

Comment: `e` should have the same size as other variables.

Comment: See this code: `Displayed:
\[ \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\frac{x}{n}}\] or in line 
$\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$ with variations $\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\dfrac{x}{n}}$.`

Comment: Or I think the summation is making you confusing. If you wish to change the size of the summation symbol for inline, use: `$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$`

Answer (score 1):

- if you use `latex`, than instead `$$` for displayed math environment use `\[` and `\]`.
- for operators  are normally used roman font face, i.e. it should be `sin` and  `e` and not *`sin`* and *`e`*.
- instead to use bigger "e" i would rather use one of the following possibilities:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \begin{document}
  \[
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} \,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x}{n}}
  \]
  \[
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} \,\mathrm{e}^{x/n}
  \]
  \[
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} \exp\Bigl(-\frac{x}{n}\Bigr)
  \]
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: The square root depends on `n` and should be inside the summation :-)

Comment: @Sigur, ups, i overlooked this. i will correct this asap.